# Retrieve object in DataGridView through ContextMenu submenu inherited from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, datagridview, contextmenu

I have a project with multiple forms. Many of these forms have a DataGridView with DataBound Items, they are bound to instances of Class `Ticket`. I want to give all these DataGridViews the same ContextMenu. When a user right-clicks on a row in a DataGridView, and then clicks on an item in the contextmenu, something has to be done with the databound `Ticket`.

To achieve this, I created a base form which the other forms inherit from. In this base form I defined the ContextMenu (I haven't worked with contextmenu's before, so it was trial and error, and I don't know for sure this is the best way to do it.):

```
public ContextMenuStrip ContextTicket;

public frmBaseForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ContextTicket = new ContextMenuStrip();

    var itemEdit = ContextTicket.Items.Add("Edit ");
    itemEdit.Click += itemEdit_Click;

    var itemAssign = ContextTicket.Items.Add("Assign to");

    foreach (var user in Selection.Users)
    {
        ToolStripItem item = (itemAssign as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(user.Name);
        item.Click += itemAssign_Click;
    }

    var itemSetToFixed = ContextTicket.Items.Add("Set Fixed");
    itemSetToFixed.Click += itemSetToFixed_Click;
}
```

The idea being: the contextmenu has 3 menuitem's; Edit, Set Fixed and Assign. the Assign Item has a submenu, which is dynamically filled with the `users` stored in `Selection` instance. These menus and the submenu are all created perfectly fine in the forms which inherit from the base form.

The functionality behind the "Set Fixed" item I got working, I retrieve the relevant `Ticket` like so:

```
public void itemSetToFixed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ticket = getTicket(sender);

    /*
       Do something with Ticket
    */
}

private Ticket getTicket(object sender)
{
    try
    {
        ToolStripItem clickedItem = sender as ToolStripItem;

        ContextMenuStrip owner = clickedItem?.Owner as ContextMenuStrip;
        DataGridView control = owner?.SourceControl as DataGridView;            

        var obj = control?.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem; 

        if (obj is Ticket)
        {
            return (Ticket)obj;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error", "Unable to retrieve ticket information from selection.");
        return null;
    }    
}
```

I have trouble retrieving the selected `Ticket` from the SubMenu's of the Assign Item, though. When I come from a submenu, the `clickedItem.Owner` is a `ToolStripDropDownMenu` and I can't seem to get to the `DataGridView` level anymore.

How can I get from the ContextMenu's submenu, to the original clicked row (ie `Ticket`) in the DataGridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your DataGridView mouse click event listening method, treat the sender as a DataGridView:

```
private void DataGridViewMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        if (dgv != null)
        {
            // find the current index
            int currentIndex = dgv.CurrentRow.Index;
            // find the current Ticket
            Ticket currentTicket = dgv.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as Ticket;

            ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
            // set up the context menu here...
            menu.Show(dgv, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }
    }
}
```

The dgv and currentTicket objects can be assigned another way, if you prefer:

```
DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView) sender;
Ticket currentTicket = (Ticket) dgv.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
```

As far as finding the current index, the user must have clicked something already before this method will work properly... so it would be wise to put checks in there to make sure that this has been done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Looks good! Didn't think of using the gridview event. I'll test it Monday. This probably means I have to make the gridview hereditary too, doesn't it? Or will it be enough if they have the same name?

Comment: The name of the DataGridView should not matter. What *does* matter, though, is that you wire the method to the correct mouse click event(s). Otherwise, you won't have the correct MouseEventArgs object (which will make displaying the menu more difficult). You should be able to use the same event handling method for each of the DataGridViews if you choose to. One that works for this purpose is the `CellClick` event. I don't believe you should need to edit your DataGridViews at all to make this work.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thanks so far, May get back to you when I try it.

Comment: That was a lot easier than I imagined! Thanks so much for your help.